# Using LDPC coding package with BSC channel only

Tags: python

so I am using this python based ldpc package https://hichamjanati.github.io/pyldpc/ In this package for some constraints of my project I cannot use the SNR values. I can only apply bit flips with certain probabilities to the entire encoded message. But with this package, it seems SNR value is a must.

```
from pyldpc import make_ldpc, encode, decode, get_message
n = 15
d_v = 4
d_c = 5
snr = 20
H, G = make_ldpc(n, d_v, d_c, systematic=True, sparse=True)
k = G.shape[1]
print('K:', k)

v = np.random.randint(2, size=k)
print('V:', v)

y = encode(G, v, snr)
print('Encode:', y)

if y[1] == 1:
    y[1] = 0
else:
    y[1] = 1
print('Corrupted:', y)

d = decode(H, y, snr)
print('Decode:', y)

x = get_message(G, d)
print('Get message:', x)
```

(ignore the snr variable I turned it off in a way).

When I went ahead and forcibly turned off the SNR argument and applied bit-flip errors on my own the decoder was not able to correct it, giving a message

```
UserWarning: Decoding stopped before convergence. You may want to increase maxiter
  warnings.warn("Decoding stopped before convergence.")
```

Is there a proper way to implement simple bit flips in this package? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bitflip almost equal to inverse of sign of soft data after

```
encode(G, v, snr)
```

I think you've made too much errors and decoder can't decode it.

p.s. mention that this package use SP-decoding, which very sensitive to correctness of SNR estimation (and constructed to work only with gaussian noise, not with channel with erasures or inversions of analog input data).
Better to try using of MS-decoder which not sensitive to snr estimation.